# ImportError: No module named 'pvlib'

Tags: ipython, pvlib

I am using Jupiter notebook ipython for solar power forecasting. When I import the pvlib it gives error "ImportError: No module named 'pvlib'".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQf7f.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

`ImportError` basically says that the library/package you are trying to import is not available. So try re-installing that package and check once again. Hopefully, it will work. If you feel that this is not the problem then kindly let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the pvlib installation instructions: https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html